# Send data to the server using ExtJs

Tags: extjs

is it the write syntax ??in the params section i want to  add this field to send to the server but not working

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({

                url:'http://localhost:8084/org.servlet/url_servlet',
                method:'GET',


 params:{

        myname:document.getElementById('firstname').value//this is the field i want to send to the servlet

    } ,  
              success: function (response){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Succesfully added ');

     },
          failure: function (){
           Ext.Msg.alert('Error in server');
    }
```

Comment: i am doing this but not working plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with ajax

Example Code

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'page.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        // process server response here
    }
});
```

Comment: it is useful thanks but will you be little elaborate about sending the two fields??should i write those name & surname fields into success:function() please

Comment: add name and surname fields to params section

Comment: Ext.Ajax.request({
    
                    url:'http://localhost:8084/org.servlet/url_servlet',
                    method:'GET',
                    
                 
     params:{
            
          
           id:1
        firstname:firstname.getvalue();
                  
        } ,  
                  success: function (response){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Succesfully added ');
                
         },
              failure: function (){
               Ext.Msg.alert('Error in server');
        }